# 4 Images side by side to take up entire width of browser window

Tags: html, css, image

I have 4 images (all the same width and all the same height) that I want displayed side by side on the very top of the webpage, but the trick is that is needs to take up the entire browsers width `$(window).width()` in jQuery.

My questions are:

First, is this possible?

If so:

1. What is the best way to do this for all browser widths (or most of
   them)?
2. Should it be 1 image instead of 4?
3. What are the advantages/disadvantages of either way (1 image vs. 4 images, and vice versa)?
4. Do I have to use jQuery or another language to calculate the screen's width and load up different size images for each different size screen width?  Or can this be done with CSS natively?
5. What width size is recommended to use on, either, all 4 images, or if I make these images 1 image, what width would be recommended than?

NOTES:  I don't want to stretch the images wider, cause that will cause it to look distorted, but if I have big images and size them down, than it affects the load of the page (dropping performance).  How to do this so that I don't have to make any sacrifices in look and/or performance?  If possible, I would also like it to look right in phones... but that's not a huge priority, but would be nice, if possible.

Comment: i am not sure what you want to do. you say you dont want images to stretch but take up entire width

Comment: I have 4 images that need to fill the entire width of a browser.  Any width that is shown.  I don't want the images to stretch up in width, but maybe resize down is my only other option.  In any case, what size width is recommended for this on each image?

Comment: i think you need something like this http://adaptive-images.com/

Comment: Can there be space between the images? A drawing would ne helpful.

Comment: No space between images... I'll try and get something together in Photoshop to illustrate.  @btevfik - I can't use that because, unfortunately the server has NO PHP or APACHE support!

Comment: @SolomonClosson then you can do this http://drupal.org/project/cs_adaptive_image

Comment: @btevfik - Sorry, I'm not using a drupal environment either.  I wouldn't be able to if the server does not provide PHP anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images need to be set to 50% the width of the parent element. In my example that parent element is the body:

```
<img class='half-width-img' src='http://wallpapers.free-review.net/wallpapers/42/Big_wave.jpg'/>
<img class='half-width-img' src='http://wallpapers.free-review.net/wallpapers/42/Big_wave.jpg'/>
<img class='half-width-img' src='http://wallpapers.free-review.net/wallpapers/42/Big_wave.jpg'/>
<img class='half-width-img' src='http://wallpapers.free-review.net/wallpapers/42/Big_wave.jpg'/>
```

Css:

```
.half-width-img{
width:25%;
height:auto;
float:left;
}
html,body{
margin:0 0 0 0;
padding:0 0 0 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j7L4h/2/

Comment: Note: 1 image is better then 4 and if you want that just use 1 image and set its width to be 100%;

Comment: The images are actual images, NOT solid color images.  That wouldn't make any sense to have solid color images, in that case I would just do `background-color`

Comment: o, that was just something to make sure it was running ignore background-color:blue; If you actually look at it, they are images.

Comment: @SolomonClosson ok using this example, i guess you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/j7L4h/1/

Comment: o, for some reason I thought you want 2 images that are on top, then 2 again under it. I edited that now

Comment: Ok, thanks, but what should I make the images width size to be?  For this not to distort the image tremendously...

Comment: Or should I just use 1 image?

Comment: Given that a vast majority screen sizes are below 2560x1600 you just need 2560/4 or 640px

Comment: 2560 is the max for the majority?  Where do you get these statistics?

Comment: How would this approach scale down for iphones and other phones?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26499/discussion-between-user1938671-and-solomon-closson)

Comment: @user1938671 - Sorry, just now seeing this comment, I'm waiting for you in the chat area.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend, if possible, making the 4 images into 1 image if you're concerned with scalability. You can also then specify the dimensions of the image, which helps load time since the browser doesn't have to figure out the dimensions of each image (which is what it would need to do if you gave it percentages for width size). If this is for some kind of background, perhaps, edit the last image in such a way that when the browser expands to a greater width than the image dimension, it repeats forever (e.g. background-repeat in CSS)...